# Add a multidimension PHP Array at the end of each item of a multidimension array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here are the two Multi-dimension arrays explained.

```
// Categories Array
$categories = array(
  array('cat_id'=>'1', 'cat_name' => 'Category One', 'cat_data' => 'Some Data'), 
  array('cat_id'=>'2', 'cat_name' => 'Category Two', 'cat_data' => 'Some Data'),
  array('cat_id'=>'3', 'cat_name' => 'Category Tree', 'cat_data' => 'Some Data')
);
// Products Array (One $products array is to be placed inside every new category.
$products = array(
  array('p_id'=>'1', 'p_name'=>'Product One'), 
  array('p_id'=>'2', 'p_name'=>'Product Two'), 
  array('p_id'=>'3', 'p_name'=>'Product Three')
);
```

Here The `$products` needs to be placed inside every element of `$category` array, with a **key**  of some random key take for eg '**product_list**'.

Here is the result like

```
$category = array(
  array('cat_id'=>'1', 'cat_name' => 'Category One', 'cat_data' => 'Some Data', 'product_list'=>array()),
  array('cat_id'=>'2', 'cat_name' => 'Category Two', 'cat_data' => 'Some Data', 'product_list'=>array())
);
```

Please scroll Right for the above code to see the last element added to these elements.

Please tell how to add that multi-dimension array with a key to each n every element of the `$category` array. Thanks

Comment: Ok, was so much easier ;)

Comment: that relation is not required here, that is to be used in some different business logic, here I just wasn't able to add that multidimensional array with a key, but I figured it out quite easy one. thanks for interest bro.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code.

```
foreach($categories as $key=>$value)
{
     $categories[$key]['product_list'] = $products;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem?

```
foreach ($categories as &$category) {
    $category['product_list'] = $products;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying several attemps, I solved this problem by myself by just a simple code. here it is.

`$categories['product_list'] = $products;`

Hope, users finding this type of problem this useful. Thanks